# Change bootstrap nav-bar right items selected color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for my project and I done some mofigication with my own CSS file. however I need to change bootstrap nav-bar right side items selected color. No matter how hard I tried it want change with my CSS file

```css
.navbar-static-top{
    background-color: #3498db;
}

 .navbar-brand
{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color:white;
  font-size: 190%;
}

body {
  font-size: 9px;
} 

table-hover{
    background-color: #FFF;
}

thead th {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: Left;
    background-color: #3498db;
    font-size: 11px;
}

tbody td {
     height: 20px;
    padding: px px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: right;
}

.vertical-center {
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.input-sm {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}


input[readonly] {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* any other styles */
}

.nav li{
    padding-right:10px;
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #FFF;
   }

.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 120%;
}

.input-sm {
  height: 25px;
  padding: px px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#submitbtn{
    align: center;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
  margin: 0; 
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Leave Application</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>   
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ><a href="sessionstart.php">My Leaves</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="request.php">Application</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and this is sample image how my site currently appeared in browser [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6md0T.jpg)

I want change this gray color to white color with black text for selected item. how can I do this ?

Comment: Add your HTML for better undestanding or create a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Use developer tools for this. I think `.active` causes your problem. Bootstrap may use this class and so it overrides your styles. Either you use `.active` in your selector or you use `!important`. I would prefer to use `.active`.

Comment: I tried so many times with many different CSS styles but non of them worked. !! then I ditch the bootstrap and move to W3 CSS. it's cleaner and way more easier to use.thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you are loading your custom css after bootstrap, otherwise it wont override it.

Secondly make sure that your css rules points to DOM element exactly the same or more specific then bootstrap does.

Personally I prefix parent node with my own id or class and refer to it in my css. This guarantees me that I always use more specific css declarations then bootstrap does.

But if it doesn't makes sense to you you can simply use !important after your css proporty, but I recommend avoiding it at all costs unless you exactly know that there is no other way

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem here with the linking your external css file and bootstrap file

you need place to them like this

so that browser read the last css update from the file.

Comment: No I added my css file to the last

Answer (score 0):

now, try this.
just add below code to your CSS.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background: #000000;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: in this CSS, You can give your custom class to make different from your Default bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Thanks but this makes my whole nav bar to black color. I only want to right side <li class="active"> background color white

Answer (score 0):

As you provided the code it is working on codepen.

I think, the problem is css file not linked in HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
nav.navbar .navbar-collapse ul.navbar-right li.active a {
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}
```